# send video from sdcard to perticular emaill address

Tags: android, video, sd-card

```
video attachment can not send to particular email address.
```

I have created an application that sends an email with a recording video, when the intent is fired and email is chosen as the app to send the attachment, you can see that there is an attachment but the attachment is not delivered

```
 package com.example.emailnew;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("video/mp4");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"123@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "video");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "evidence");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,   Uri.parse("file://sdcard/Pictures/Mycameravideos/VIDS.mp4"));//pngFile 

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("video/mp4");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                "mail--id" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures/Mycameravideos/VIDS.mp4"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));\
```

and ya don't forget to add this below permission to your menifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: sir.. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> can not find in the permission list

Comment: Then add it in your manifest and try. You are getting error because you have not added permission and it is trying to get  the attachment from SD-card and you have not set permission to read data from SD-card.

Comment: Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("video/mp4")emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
         "mansoor3k@gmail.com" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "video");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures/Mycameravideos/VIDS.mp4"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
emailIntent.setType("video/mp4");
startActivity(emailIntent);

Comment: What;s the problem you are getting if you use above code.

Comment: sir,i gave permission internet,write external storage...but i cant find the permision "read external storage" in the permission list

Comment: Can't you copy it from here and paste it in your manifest file?

Comment: no sir,, i mean  users permision name "read external storage" not find in the permmission list

Comment: Try to clean your project or if you are using eclipse just restart your eclipse once. I don't know what is happening with you but this code perfectly working fine in my case and also i am able to use read external storage permission.

Comment: sir..i gave permissions .but can not send attachment video

Comment: Are you getting mail or not?

Comment: i got mail sir..but not get attachment

Comment: Okay then check whether the file you are attaching in your mail is available at given path or not.

Comment: Do one thing upload all one by one here http://pastie.org/ and give me a link of all file.

Comment: Yes i got it, now wait for some time let me check and i will get back to you.

Comment: @user3367503, your code is perfectly working from myside, i don't get why it is not working for you.

Comment: SIR, can u tel about set video path?

Comment: I did't get you, what do you mean exactly.

Comment: Okay one more thing, what is the size of this `VID.mp4` file. Like `2MB` or `10MB` howmuch MB it is?